# Can we take money from our boss if he does not pay commision and good salary?

Tags: halal-haram

I have boss, he forces us to work 12 hours continuously and some time give 1 hours and half hour break he doesn't pay us commission on selling products and our salary is very low can we take the money our selves without him knowing.

Answer (score 2):

The Prophet  sallallaahu  `alayhi  wa  sallam ( may  Allaah exalt his mention ) said:

> **“The gifts of employees are unlawful taking of spoils.”**

[Ahmad - Al-Albaani graded it Saheeh (sound)]

Ibn Qudaamah  may  Allaah  have  mercy  upon  him said in Al-Mughni: “Imaam Ahmad said in a narration by Muhanna: **“If a garment is given to a man to sell it, and he did so, and the buyer gifted him a handkerchief, then the handkerchief is for the owner of the garment.” He said so because the gift of the handkerchief was made because of the sale, so the handkerchief was an increase in price, and any price increases made during the contract negotiation should be included in it.”**

[Ref-Fatwa](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=231187)

It is not permissible for you to take this commission without permission from the company you work for because gifts and commissions for the employee without the permission of the employer are not permissible.

If you think that they are taking more work from you than you agreed for, you can ask for more salary, or find some other work. But this does not allow you to steal from him or take any kind of commission without him knowing.
Their is only one situation where you can steal from boss, when they are not letting you leave the work even when you ask to(assuming their was no agreement of minimum work period). And you have no other choice. But in your case it seems you agreed to work in this pay and you have not asked them to increase it. Now if they force you to work(on gun point or some way that forceful), when you don't want to work there in that pay, or some situation like that, only in situations like that you can steal(as much as they owe you for the over time). Otherwise stealing is forbidden in Islam and it is one of the grave major sins.
But in your case it does not seem like that kind of situation.